# How can i achieve this output using Bootstrap 5.2.3 only

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-5

I am writing a simple html activity that will allow me to have an output similar on this image i provided bellow. I want to appear as is or the same with this layout. The task dont need a CSS it just a bootstrap it self is need to be used.

Here is also my code but i guess im doing it wrong.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So you are using 5th or 3rd version of Bootstrap?

Comment: am using 5.2.3 version

Comment: It was _hint_ to fix your tags...

Comment: could you please help me how can i resolved this?

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the code you've provided?

Comment: I cannot achieve same output with the picture i provided

Answer (score 1):

You can nest `row` inside `row` to have sub-grid, rinse and repeat.

Just don't forget, that there must be `row` followed by `col-*` and only than another `row`

```css
div {
  min-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Body content goes here -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 bg-success text-white">
      <h1>Hello!</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 bg-warning"></div>
    <div class="col-4 bg-secondary"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 bg-success"></div>
    <div class="col-4 bg-warning"></div>
    <div class="col-4 bg-secondary">.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-8 bg-secondary text-white">col-8</div>


    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-6 bg-info"></div>
        <div class="col-6 bg-danger"></div>
        <div class="col-6 bg-danger"></div>
        <div class="col-6 bg-info"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks it works.. but is it possible not to add customized css?

Comment: @KlintMasha I have added CSS only to keep empty div's. Add content and remove this CSS